# java GUI programming tools?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

which is one is the best java GUI generating tool

1. NetBeans
2. Jigloo

Please suggest me if you have any other choices.

I need the following functionalities:

- Drag and drop feature
- able to add code manually after some point of time
- code readability
- need to rename variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetBeans' Matisse is very good and flexible. You can rename variables, the generated code is relatively readable, Drag and Drop is supported, and you can always manipulate the screen manually (although you cannot (or better - shouldn't) touch the generated code.

Comment: Thanks Bozho .. i am using Netbean's only.But here i design the GUI and get the file outside and added my application logic after i am not able to copy this file to the original file which is present in NetBeans .. how to do this?

Comment: Netbeans does have a nice GUI builder, but after a certain point in the development process, I often have to "break" the connection between the GUI builder and the code. The GUI code in the IDE is regenerated based on ".form" file associated with the Java file. You can just erase the ".form" file and you will be able to do whatever you want with the Java source. You just won't be able to use the GUI builder with that file again.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Visual editor](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/) for Eclipse.

Comment: Matisse has a better designer, but VE works better with existing code.

Comment: Matiese has been ported and shown to work in Eclipse. Its rather funny that Eclipse has to import this functionality :P

Answer (score 0):

cloudgarden for eclipse.

Comment: yes you are talking about Jigloo GUI Builder

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JBuilder lover, but it does have a rather good GUI Editor.

I aged 10 years trying to sort out GRIDBAG, JBuilder saved me a load of grey hair!

Comment: But JBuilder is commercial .. i need opensource

Comment: ... Then add that as one of your requirements.